# How to get total number of registered users *at* each month?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table like this:

users:

```
id (int) | date_registered (int)
1          1394746963
...        ...
```

And I want to make a pretty chart showing the number of registered users for each month (*not* the number of users *registering* per month, but the total number of *registered* users at that point in time).

So, for example, the data returned might look like this:

```
date        | registeredUsers
2013-10-00    15
2013-11-00    55
2013-12-00    96
2014-01-00    150
2014-02-00    225
```

I know how to get the number of users registered at a certain point in time, that's easy:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE date_registered < :unixTimeStamp
```

But how do I write a query that will return the number of registered users at multiple points in time (namely, at the end or beginning of each month)?

Comment: Are you wanting to pull directly from SQL or is there perhaps a php or something you can work with?

Comment: @XIII Yes, I can do it in PHP, but I *am* curious if it's possible to do in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to group by date.

```
SELECT date, COUNT(id) FROM users GROUP BY MONTH(date_registered).
```

Comment: Change `date` to `date_registered AS [date]` and `COUNT(id)` to `COUNT(id) AS registeredUsers` and you may want to change the `GROUP BY` to [include year](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: Thanks for your help! This appears to get the number of users that registered each month, not the total number of registered users *at* each month, though. Any ideas how to get it to return the total number of registered users *at* each month?

Comment: Does `Count(distinct id)` help?